# Forward QUERY_STRING in .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Suppose I want to rewrite from

```
http://example.com/test?data=abcxyz
```

to

```
 http://example.com/index.php?module=test&data=abcxyz
```

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^test?(.*)$ index.php?module=test&$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work, the QUERY_STRING becomes `module=test&s`. (The whole string data=abcxyz become s).
How can I accomplish this task?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flag to this, the QSA flag :)

```
RewriteRule ^test?(.*)$ index.php?module=test&$1 [L,QSA]
```

Explanation from here : [Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combin

Comment: Thank you very much! Stackoverflow is such an awesome place!

Comment: "QSA" is the key